# Datagridview SelectedRows.Count is always zero when selecting last row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview where I have set the allow user to add row property to false.

I have also made it only possible to have a fullrowselect on the datagridview.

A user adds rows to the datagrid by pressing the "+" button of the toolstrip. The DGV was created by dragging a datasourse to a form that added the binding navigator toolstrip.

My problem is that in my code for row deletion, i check

```
private void bindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (dgvUsers.SelectedRows.Count > 0 && dgvUsers.Rows[0].Selected)
            MessageBox.Show("You cannot remove the user admin");
        else
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove the user?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                int code = 0;

                UserService userService = new UserService();

                if (dgvUsers.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
                {
                    int selectedrowindex = dgvUsers.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

                    DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dgvUsers.Rows[selectedrowindex];

                    code = (int)(selectedRow.Cells[0].Value);

                    if (GlobalClass.SessionId == "admin")
                    {
                        userService.RemoveUsers(code);
                    }
                    else
                        MessageBox.Show("Only username 'admin' can remove users");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

When I select the last row for deletion, SelectedRows.Count = 0. But it is "1" when I select any other row. Why is this?

Comment: It's hard to find out your issue without any code. How you add the rows? Post your code please.

Comment: Your code will run if one or more rows are selected. If a row is selected, selectedrows.count = 1. Check if your if condition happens after any deselection of the row.

Comment: @Arin Ghazarian. Edited.

Comment: @chiapa. When I select any other row other than the last, selectedrows.count = 1. When I select the last row, selectedrows.count = 0.

Comment: When you select the last row is it highlighted (unless you didn't modify this behavior)?
Are you sure you don't have any event that change selection?

Comment: The last row is highlighted. I have no event that changes selection.

Comment: I think the changes didn't commit, try to commit them using *CommitEdit()* method of *DataGridView* object.

Comment: Please show more code as in theory you are doing everything right

Comment: I think the best way to check for selected rows is this: `myDgv.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)`. http://stackoverflow.com/q/12469484/1977778

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you check if the "SelectionMode" property is set to FullRowSelect?

In the MSDN is written:

"The SelectionMode property must be set to FullRowSelect or RowHeaderSelect for the SelectedRows property to be populated with selected rows."

Comment: It is set to FullRowSelect as I stated in the question.

Comment: If you want clicking on a row to select the row, then you probably want to set CellClickAction to RowSelect. Also make sure the SelectTypeRow property is set to the default or some other settings that allows the selection of multiple rows. You might also want to turn off the selection of cells using SelectTypeCell.

Comment: There really is no more code to show. I created the DGV by dragging a users datasource to a form. The bindingnavigator and "+" button to and a row is automatically created. I set the FullRowSelect from the preperties window of visual studio.

Comment: Can you check if you use "Selected" property to true for the last row? I mean to select it programmatically and then check the "SelectedRows.Count".

Comment: When I click on the delete button on the last row, that row dissapears even before the code reaches the try{ line. So when I select the last row programmatically, an error is returned as out of bounds. Why does the row get removed on click?

Comment: Does it have any data or is it blank?

Comment: Can you use the DataGridViewCellEventArgs instead of EventArgs.
So you can get the selected row -> int cRow =dgvUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex]; You can check the e.RowIndex to know if there is a selected row.

Comment: I have solved it by deleting the toolstrip delete button generated automatically and adding my own. Thanks.

Comment: Not worked with RowHeaderSelect but worked with FullRowSelect for me.