# How to get number of rows selected using Cell Select as Selection Mode in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

Here I can retrieve the information about selected cell like so.

```
DataGridViewCell selectedCell = productSpecGrid.SelectedCells[0];
int rowIndex = selectedCell.RowIndex;
int colIndex = selectedCell.ColumnIndex;
```

Next, I am aiming to get number of rows selected, not cells, just rows.

This is how I tried it:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < productSpecGrid.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
{
    count++;
}
MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());
```

**Testing**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

**Question**

Using specifically Cell Select as my selection mode. How do I get the count of each row selected?

**Edit**

Looking here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/selected-cells-rows-and-columns-datagridview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

It states: **Use the SelectedRows property. To enable users to select rows, you must set the SelectionMode property to FullRowSelect or RowHeaderSelect.**

This is the reason why I get `0` in my output.

**Edit 2**

I have found this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23949743/12485722

Just not sure that he means by

> You can either call Count

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < productSpecGrid.SelectedRows.Count; i++) { count++; }` - [a.k.a. `count = productSpecGrid.SelectedRows.Count`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111227-00/?p=8793).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Datagridview SelectedRows.Count is always zero when selecting last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20967427/datagridview-selectedrows-count-is-always-zero-when-selecting-last-row)

Comment: @GSerg Hi, I'd like to specifically use `Cell Select` instead of `Full Row`

Comment: Then infer the rows from the SelectedCells.

Comment: @GSerg Infer? What does what mean

Comment: It [means](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/infer?q=infer) each selected cell [tells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell?view=net-5.0#properties) you what row it belongs to. Thus, it's trivial to advance from a set of selected cell to the corresponding set of selected rows.

Comment: If you have the selection mode set to something that is NOT ROW oriented, like the `CellSelect` mode… then the grids `SelectedRows` collection is NOT used. That is why when you try to grab its row count… it will always be zero (0). Just counting the rows in the `SelectedCells` collection will not work. There may be “multiple” selected cells on the same row. To get the total number of "selected rows" from the `SelectedCells` collection, you will need to get the number of the “different” row indexes from all the rows in the `SelectedCells` collection.

Comment: He means: `var count = productSpecGrid.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Select(c => c.RowIndex).Distinct().Count();`. Good day :)

Comment: @dr.null Thank you :)